# How do I enable remote celery debugging in PyCharm?

Tags: debugging, celery, pycharm

I'm trying to find some instructions on how to enable PyCharm debugging within my celery processes on a remote machine.  The remote machine is running Ubuntu 14.04.

I am running PyCharm 4.x.

I've seen some other information that alludes others have it working, but haven't been able to locate any proper instructions.

Answer (score 47):

You can have a `Run Configuration` to run your `celery` workers which then allows you to debug simply by clicking the `debug` button. Here is how I set that up in PyCharm 5:

[image: pycharm celery]

You need to set up a remote python interpreter and then set other configs like the image above. Note that the `Working directory` is pointing to the `bin` folder of the remote interpreter with `celery` installed.

Comment: this solution worked for me in pycharm 2020 pro edit: i suppose workdir was what's missing

Comment: I had to put the full path to the `celery` executable in IntelliJ 2021.1.

Answer (score 26):

For **Windows**, tested in with Celery >= 4.0

Add a new (Run/Debug) configuration of type "**Python**":

Then, Under configuration tab:
switch the first option (Target to run) from "***Script path***" to "***Module name***" and fill in the value:

```
celery.bin.celery
```

like the snapshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, was looking for this!

Comment: Thanks, I found `-P solo` must be added

Comment: I had to use module name `celery`, not `celery.bin.celery`

Answer (score 15):

Just add the following config:

```
from celery import current_app
current_app.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
current_app.conf.CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

Doing so makes celery execute in the same thread as the currently executing thread.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, most solutions don't work on Windows. (There was a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150910/how-can-i-use-pycharm-to-locally-debug-a-celery-worker) specifically about that, but unfortunately it got closed as a duplicate of this one. So I'll answer that question here now.)

The problem is that on Windows, the standalone celery command is a batch file, so PyCharm cannot attach the Python debugger to it.

Up until Celery 3.x, you can create a `manage.py` run configuration and call the `celery worker` command on it.

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm run configuration for running manage.py celery worker]

Note that you don't need to set `--app` here, as the application is defined by the management command via `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Unfortunately, the `celery` management command was a feature of the `django-celery` library, which isn't supported by Celery 4.x. As of yet, I haven't found a solution for Celery 4.x.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Figure: Run/Debug Configurations]

I have PyCharm 2021.3(Professional Edition) and my library:

- Python==3.8.9
- celery==5.2.7

I use macOS M1. I followed the below steps for this problem:

1. There are `Edit Configurations..` in the option `Run`.
2. Click `'+'` button which figured showed blue arrow and add new configuration.
3. Add Python configuration.
4. Select configuration `Module name` instead of `Script Path` as showed red arrow in `Figure`.
5. Add `Parameters` like `--workdir=/path/to/your_proj_direction -A your_proj.dir.celery_app worker -l info`. It need to `--workdir` parameter for celery handle path. Except this, you write any script to start celery worker without `celery` word at the beginning.
6. Add `Python interpreter` as  your proj interpreter.
7. Add `Working directory` to your virtual env path which installed celery library.
8. Click `Apply`.
9. You can use normal Debug PyCharm this configuration. İf you run configuration as Debug, PyCharm will start celery worker and you can debug.

Comment: It also works on PyCharm 2023.2.3 (Professional Edition)! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

in Windows , Add the following params in your debugging conf in Pycharm

```
-A YouAppName worker  --loglevel=debug -P solo --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gevent for Celery do not forget to check `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger > Gevent Compatible` checkbox.

Comment: Life-saving comment

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [@Assam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7VtJ.png) answer:

on linux\ubuntu simply choosing the "Script Path -> Module name" = `celery` did the trick for me

[image: [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/149556/assem]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PyCharm 2017 and had to do something very similar to the answers above, but I specifically had to put the full/absolute path name to `celery` in the "Script" field

Also, I'm not sure if PyCharm 4 has this feature, but newer versions allow you to attach directly to a running python process by going to Run > Attach to Local Process...

This allows you to run celery however you were before (in the terminal, perhaps) then allow Pycharm to take over

Answer (score 1):

Example of configuration settings for celery on mac when using `venv`.

Where parametr`app` is name of `Celery` object from your python code

`app = Celery('project')`

[image: Configuration settings celery for mac]

Answer (score 0):

My working configuration:

- Script: `/home/app/env/bin/celery`
- Script parameters: `worker -B -n qrc -Q qrc -l info --app=backend.celery`

  - Where `-B` is for celerybeet,
    `-n` is node name,
    `-Q` is queue name,
    `-l` is log level, and
    `--app` is the app name, a django app with celery.py next to settings.py in my case.
- Working directory: `/home/app/server/` ie my django root folder

Comment: How do you start the web server and the celery worker at the same time?