# How can I use PyCharm to locally debug a Celery worker?

Tags: python, celery, pycharm, virtualenv

I have an existing Django project with a virtualenv. After activating the venv, I can run Celery just with the command `celery`. This works on Windows, OS X and Linux.

I wanted to try PyCharm on Windows, and I'm able to get it to run my Django server (using the project's venv), but I also want to run Celery, so I can debug that as well.

I can't find a simple, straightforward guide to setting up PyCharm so I can debug Celery (in a manner will work with PyCharm on any platform).

Comment: I would just use the "attach to local process" feature to connect to the running worker. Found in the run menu of the professional edition.

Comment: @Bluehorn "No process to attach to"

Answer (score 81):

This is what I do to run celery

Go to `Edit Configuration`, then select the '+' icon to add new Python script and enter the celery path, other parameters and working directory. You can specify environment variables and bottom of that you have the option to select parent environment to include as well. Also, don't forget to choose your python interpreter for taking care of virtual environment.

[image: running celery using pycharm]

Comment: If you are using `virtualenv`, you might want to change the `Script` path to point to your `env`'s location, like so: `env/bin/celery`

Comment: I noticed that this does not work with `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True`, as it does not stop on break points. Try setting it to False instead, which should be the default anyway.

Comment: @phobic it is not needed to set always_eager=True, you run the script in debug mode, it will work.

Comment: This works on Linux, but last I've tried this doesn't work on Windows (as OP requested). The standalone `celery` command is a batch file there, so PyCharm cannot attach the Python debugger to it.

Comment: I've outlined a workaround for Celery 3.x on Windows here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48868014/6278

Comment: I run it with the same configuration. This should be marked as the right response.

Comment: For Celery 4.x and better Celery 3.x solution see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57817731/4474576

Comment: This is not working for me. I use Celery 5.x on Linux-5.4.0-42-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.10. I set up the project as described, then run the abovementioned config in debug mode. The code stops at my breakpoint (at least pycharm makes me think it did; in debug window, I have Debugger and Console tabs, and the breakpoint line becomes blue in the background). And then it hangs. In Console, I cannot print anything, in debugger, nothing is shown, and I cannot advance the code (at least, not by any means known to me).

Comment: If you've been experiencing `The curl client requires the pycurl library` error, uninstalling `pycurl` and installing with `PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" pip install --no-cache-dir pycurl` helped me.