# Django-Celery: importing from another app into project's celery.py file

Tags: django, pycharm, celery, django-celery

I am following the tutorial on [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) to get periodic tasks defined in my django project working.

The article suggests having a `celery.py` file of the form:

```
    from celery import Celery
    from celery.schedules import crontab

    app = Celery()

    @app.on_after_configure.connect
    def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
            # Calls test('hello') every 10 seconds.
            sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, my_task.s('hello'), name='add every 10')
            )

    @app.task
    def my_task(arg):
            print(arg)
```

which works. Now this is good but I don't want to define my tasks locally. my question is, how can I add tasks from other apps?

I have created a blank project called `my_proj` and it has two apps: `my_proj` and `app_with_tasks`. the `celery.py` file above is at the root level in `my_proj` app's directory and I want to add periodic tasks from `app_with_tasks` 's `tasks.py` file.

I do have `app_with_tasks` listed in Installed-apps for `my_proj` settings file but I still can't import anything from an app to anther.

my understanding is that I should use:

```
from app_with_tasks.tasks import task1
```

but `my_proj` will then show as unresolved reference in PyCharm.

Comment: what is the command that you use to start the celery server/daemon?

Comment: `celery -A my_proj beat`, but I am not there yet. I believe I have missed a trivial step as nowhere in my project files can I make an import of anything from `app_with_tasks` app.

Answer (score 2):

I'll tell you what I'm using. Maybe it helps you

my_proj/celery.py

```
import os
import celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_proj.settings')

app = celery.Celery('app_django')

app.config_from_object('django.conf.settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

then in app_with_tasks, add file tasks.py

```
from my_proj.celery import app
from django.apps import apps

@app.task(bind=False)
def your_task(some_arg):
    A_Model = apps.get_model('my_proj', 'A_Model')
    ....
```

command to start celery server (restart this every time you change a task to reload tasks.py files)

```
/path/to/virtualenv/bin/celery --app=my_proj.celery:app --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=4 -n default_worker worker
```

To call the task (here you should use your add_periodic_task code)

```
from app_with_tasks.tasks import your_task
your_task.apply_async(args=[123], kwargs=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So I thought I would ignore Pycharm's warnings and run the celery beat thing anyway and strangely it does in fact beat as before. So I guess the problem wasn't really the celery side of things. It's Pycharm not recognizing the imorts for some reason.

Comment: I think that the important things to look are `--app=my_proj.celery:app` and `autodiscover_tasks`. You need to tell pycharms to use `my_proj.celery:app`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150910/how-can-i-use-pycharm-to-locally-debug-a-celery-worker

Comment: I am actually using @shared_tasks which means I don't need to bind my tasks to the app instance (google it)
Like i said, my problems aren't really with tasks as such. the IDE doesn't recognise `app_with_tasks` to start with!

Comment: Ok, so then your problem is only with pycharms, you should add that at first thing in your question and also use the pycharm tag (I added it already)

Comment: yeah only realised it now. not sure if I should keep the question as all the celery details are now kind of irrelevant I think.

Comment: Don't worry, maybe create another question or edit this one to fit your needs better.