# How to configure pycharm debug for docker-compose celery command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm, celery

I successfully configure my remote interpreter with docker-compose at Pycharm and can successfully run my server in debug mode to put breakpoints and debug the problems. Unfortunately I can't do the same thing for the docker-compose run for celery workers. When I run this command in my project folder it is working no problem but how can I run this in Pycharm debug mode ?

docker-compose run --rm app celery worker -A workers.build_events -Q build_events -l DEBUG

Comment: Trying to do the same thing... Interesting there isn't more info on this

Comment: In my case problem was resolved by specifying Path Mappings (absolute path on both sides)

Answer (score 7):

I was just able to get this working with a Python run configuration.

Make sure the working directory is set to the directory that your application code is located at inside your image.

Make sure that the script path is the path to the Celery executable. In my case, I have a virtualenv inside my application folder, so I just used a relative path from my working directory.

Make sure that your interpreter is set to a [properly configured docker compose interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#docker-compose-remote).

Finally, I've added `-P solo` to force Celery into a [single-threaded mode](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/). This is not required, but for me it makes breakpoints and debugging much easier.

Example run configuration:
  [image: Celery run configuration]

Comment: An important addition to this answer is to make sure the service in docker-compose doesn't include an "entrypoint".

Comment: If you use absolute imports on the script path, set the working directory to where the celery bin is located. This is the tidbit that got my setup working, as indicated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312809/how-do-i-enable-remote-celery-debugging-in-pycharm

Comment: @dror thank you! I've been reading various stack overflow posts all day to get my celery debugging to work and "make sure the service doesn't include an entrypoint" was the missing piece.